# Scrolling Background - smoothest way

Tags: image, parallax-scrolling

I am trying to find the best solution for drawing a scrolling background in my app in Java. For now, I have two images and I move them by 1x and put it's thread to sleep for hmm, 5ms.

The problem is here that the background is too fast. What should I do?
Probably put the thread to a longer sleep. But when I do this, the background 'freezes' - jumps for 15 pixels each step and it doesn't look smooth.

**The main question is:**
How to handle a thing like this? Should it be done by sleeping it's thread, or maybe I should make positions floats, increment them by 0.1 and move only when they are integers? << this is my idea, I don't have an idea if it would work.

We have floats: width = 1000.0 height = 1000.0;
When increment width by 0.1 in each 'update iteration' in a gameloop.
If it's a int (1001, 1002, 1003), we move the background. What do you thing? What would be the best way?

Comment: Have you tried using delta time yet?

Comment: Hmm, I heard about it, but unfortunatelly no :(

Comment: I'd recommend looking at [this](http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=24220.0) article then; it talks about different game loops and how you implement them.